# @Serializable or provide the serializer explicitly

Tags: android, kotlin, ktor

I have been working on my Android project recently and replacing Retrofit with Ktor. The debug build is working properly but problems arise in the Release build. I added all the dependencies but won't work also checked answers in Stack Overflow but can't get the proper solution for that so here is the code. Please note that my app is only for Android.

[image: Logc]

project-level build.gradle.kts

```
id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization") version "1.6.21" apply false
```

app-level build.gradle.kts

```
implementation(libs.ktor.client.core)
implementation(libs.ktor.client.android)
implementation(libs.ktor.client.serialization)
implementation(libs.ktor.client.okhttp)
implementation(libs.ktor.client.logging)

implementation(libs.logback.classic)
implementation(libs.kotlinx.serialization.json)
```

Model class

```
@Keep
@Serializable
data class SyllabusResponse(val semester: Semester?)

@Keep
@Serializable
data class Semester(
    val id: String,
    val subjects: Subject
)

@Keep
@Serializable
data class Subject(
    val theory: List<SubjectModel>,
    val lab: List<SubjectModel>,
    val pe: List<SubjectModel>
)


@Keep
@Serializable
data class SubjectModel(
    val subjectName: String,
    val code: String,
    val shortName: String,
    val credit: Double,
)
```

API interface

```
interface BitAppApiService {

    suspend fun getSubjects(course: String, courseSem: String): SyllabusResponse

    suspend fun getSubjectMarkDown(course: String, courseSem: String, subject: String): String
}
```

Ktor Module

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object KTorModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideClient(
        @ApplicationContext context: Context
    ): HttpClient =
        HttpClient(OkHttp) {
            engine {
                config {
                    cache(Cache(File(context.cacheDir, "ktor"), 50 * 1024 * 1024))
                }
            }


            install(Logging) {
                level = LogLevel.ALL
            }


            install(JsonFeature) {
                serializer = KotlinxSerializer(
                    Json {
                        ignoreUnknownKeys = true
                        isLenient = true
                    }
                )

            }
        }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApiService(
        client: HttpClient
    ): BitAppApiService = BitAppApiImp(
        client = client
    )

}
```

Progaurd

```
# Keep `Companion` object fields of serializable classes.
# This avoids serializer lookup through `getDeclaredClasses` as done for named companion objects.
-if @kotlinx.serialization.Serializable class **
-keepclassmembers class <1> {
   static <1>$Companion Companion;
}

# Keep `serializer()` on companion objects (both default and named) of serializable classes.
-if @kotlinx.serialization.Serializable class ** {
   static **$* *;
}
-keepclassmembers class <2>$<3> {
   kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer serializer(...);
}

# Keep `INSTANCE.serializer()` of serializable objects.
-if @kotlinx.serialization.Serializable class ** {
   public static ** INSTANCE;
}
-keepclassmembers class <1> {
   public static <1> INSTANCE;
   kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer serializer(...);
}

# @Serializable and @Polymorphic are used at runtime for polymorphic serialization.
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations,AnnotationDefault

-keepattributes Annotation, InnerClasses
-dontnote kotlinx.serialization.SerializationKt
```

Comment: Can you try to use the latest stable version `1.9.21` of Kotlin and the `kotlinx.serialization` framework instead of version `1.6.21`?

Comment: I tried but gives me the error `This version (1.5.1) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.9.0 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.9.21 which is not known to be compatible.` So i just rollback the version

Comment: I tried 1.9.0 but the same issue which i posted !!